# subquery not working in xampp but working in MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a table with 3 columns id, Category and Name. What i want to do is query on the basis of Category and then further query the result from the first query on the basis of Name.

```
    SELECT * From
    (SELECT * FROM table1
    where Category="Wireless") As Subquery
    where Name="Mouse"
```

This code works perfectly in MYSQL workbench but doesn't work in XAMPP. I get the following errors:

```
    An expression was expected. ( near( )
    Unexpected token. ( near ( )
    This type of clause was previously parsed. (near SELECT)
```

UPDATE: I was wrong. It is working and giving the results but it shows a cross sign in the 2nd line where I have written the statement:

```
     (SELECT * FROM table1
```

and shows the above mentioned error/warning(i don't know if it classifies as an error since the statement is working)

Comment: Put the full SQL statement into a string and print/echo it to be sure what is being sent to MySQL server.

Comment: @RyanVincent i used phpmyadmin. i am new to this. i don't know yet how to write php script